# AVPlayer, как сохранить текущее время записи

Tags: ios, swift

когда нажимаю на паузу а после на плэй музыка проигрывается заново как решить эту проблему?

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var playChange: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var timeAudio: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playbackSlider: UISlider!

if player.rate == 0 {

        let url = URL(string: ViewControllerAudioDetail.urlAudio[0])
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        player.rate = 1.0;
        player.play()
        playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        playbackSlider.tintColor = UIColor.green

        let _ = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] (time) in
            self?.playbackSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time)) / Float(seconds)
        }

    } else {

        playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        player.pause()



    }



  @IBAction func audioPlaybackSlider(_ sender: Any) {


    //перемотка аудиозвука
     let duration : CMTime = player.currentItem!.duration
    let totalDuration : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

    let value = self.playbackSlider.value
    let durationToSeek = Float(totalDuration) * value
    player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(durationToSeek),player.currentItem!.duration.timescale)) { [/*weak self*/](state) in
        //do what is relevant to your app on seeing to particular offset
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас при каждом нажатии play плеер пересоздается. По этому он начинает играть заново. вот примерно как должен выглядеть код (сам не проверял)

создать плеер один раз

```
if (player == nil) {
    let url = URL(string: ViewControllerAudioDetail.urlAudio[0])
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
    player.rate = 1.0;
    playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
}
```

play/pause

```
if player.rate == 0 {
    player.play()
    playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)    
} else {
    playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    player.pause()
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , но я уже решил проблему и если написать if(player == nil), то Приложение вылетает

Answer (score -1):

Запоминайте текущее время перед остановкой аудио: `currentTime() -> CMTime`. Далее просто возвращайтесь в тот момент воспроизведения, на котором вы остановились: `seek(to time: CMTime)`

Ссылка на [документацию](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer) по данной теме.